# R treats the subset as factor variables instead of numeric variables

Tags: r, subset, negation

In a comlex dataframe I am having a column with a net recalled salary inclusive NAs that I want to exclude plus a column with the year when the study was conducted ranging from 1992 to 2010, more or less like this:

```
q32 pgssyear
2000 1992
1000 1992
NA   1992
3000 1994
etc.
```

If I try to draw a boxplot like:

```
boxplot(dataset$q32~pgssyear,data=dataset, main="Recalled Net Salary per Month (PLN)",
    xlab="Year", ylab="Net Salary")
```

it seems to work, however NAs might distort the calculations, so I wanted to get rid of them:

```
boxplot(na.omit(dataset$q32)~pgssyear,data=dataset, main="Recalled Net Salary per Month (PLN)",
    xlab="Year", ylab="Net Salary")
```

Then I get a warning message that the length of pgsyear and q32 do not match, most likely cause I removed NAs from q32, so I tried to shorten the pgsyear, so that it does not include the rows that correspond to NAs from the q32 column:

```
   pgssyearprim <- subset(dataset$pgssyear, dataset$q32!= NA )
```

however then the pgsyearprim gets treated as a factor variable:

```
pgssyearprim
factor(0)
```

and I get the same warning message if I introduce it to the boxplot formula...

```
Levels: 1992 1993 1994 1995 1997 1999 2002 2005 2008 2010
```

Comment: Use `dataset_n <- dataset[!is.na(dataset$q32),]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course they wouldn't ... you removed some of the data only from the LHS with `na.omit(dataset$q32)~pgssyear`. Instead use `!is.na(dataset$q32)` as a subset argument

Comment: Somehow creating a separate dataset without NAs in q32 (dataset_n) and introducing it into the boxplot command worked best.